# How do I make an iPhone web app mimic a non-web app?

Tags: html, css, iphone, safari

I've been considering making a quick little iPhone web app.

I started reading about and experimenting with the special meta tags and attributes documented at [Apple's Web Apps Dev Center](https://developer.apple.com/webapps/index.php):

- viewport
- apple-mobile-web-app-capable
- apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style
- -webkit-border-radius
- -webkit-border-image
- autocorrect
- autocapitalize
- apple-touch-icon
- -webkit-text-size-adjust

This got me thinking that there must be a good guide I can follow to best mimic the default style and behavior of the device's non-web applications.

I then stumbled upon the [Joe Hewitt](http://joehewitt.com/)'s [iUI project](http://code.google.com/p/iui/).

It's got two demos that are pretty impressive:

- [Music Demo](http://iui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/REL-current/samples/music.html)
- [Digg Demo](http://iui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/REL-current/samples/digg/index.html)

Are there alternative libraries, guides, or other resources I should use?

Comment: For the record (And to everyone who stumbles here via Google): The iUI-project is now at version 0.30 (August 6, 2009).

Answer (score 3):

After testing several UI framework for iphone web app, I think [JQTouch](http://www.jqtouch.com/) is the best

Comment: And also Sencha Touch, since they integrate JQTouch and Raphael ;)

Answer (score 2):

Check out  the iUI Library- http://code.google.com/p/iui/:

Based on Joe Hewitt's iPhone navigation work, iUI has the following features:

- Create Navigational Menus and iPhone interfaces from standard HTML
- Use or knowledge of JavaScript is not required to create basic iPhone pages
- Ability to handle phone orientation changes
- Provide a more "iPhone-like" experience to Web apps (on or off the iPhone)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fancy effects that are doable with most of the libraries such as scriptaculous etc... one fancy thing going on in iPhone web apps is the "#" back button compatibility even with ajax calls, you can google for "Really Simple History" to find the right library to use in this case.

Also you may want to take a look at this if you're using jQuery: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/iphone

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [iPhoneWebDev](http://www.iphonewebdev.com/?) web site?

Also check out the book [Professional iPhone and iPod touch Programming: Building Applications for Mobile Safari](http://www.amazon.com/s?search-alias=stripbooks&field-isbn=0470251557) by Richard Wagner.

Answer (score 1):

On February 12, 2010 Andrew Flocchini of theappleblog.com wrote a guide to making website forms optimized for the iPod Touch, iPhone & iPad using the **iWebKit** framework package.

[image: name and password field change]
<sub>(source: [wordpress.com](http://gigapple.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/namechage.png?w=570&h=202))</sub>

[How-To: Create an iPhone Web App](https://web.archive.org/web/20101017210038/http://theappleblog.com:80/2010/02/12/how-to-create-an-iphone-web-app/)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best framework for iPhone Web App is `jQTouch` http://www.jqtouch.com/ It is a plug-in for jQuery. You can check out the Showtime app which is built by jQTouch.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`Swipy.js`](https://www.github.com/caktux/swipy). I didn't like the way those frameworks worked so I made this which includes other great projects:

- [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/download/#-applicationcache-inputtypes-touch-shiv-mq-cssclasses-teststyles-prefixes-load)
- [jquery.transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/)
- [Hammer.js](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js)
- [FastClick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick)
- [Waypoints.js](https://github.com/Skookum/waypoints) (not the one for scrolling)
- [Fontello](http://fontello.com/) / [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)

It progressively enhances with Modernizr, adds smooth transitions with jquery.transit, adds edge swipe back/forward navigation with Hammer.js, adds FastClick for taps, solves internal links with Waypoints and a nice nav bar with FontAwesome icons.

Enjoy :)